# ошибка при создании базы данных в python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

пытаюсь создать таблицы в бд по названию даты

```
import requests, json, sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('parser_all.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'

full_page = requests.get(url, auth=("admin","admin"))
pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))

a = []
for i in pars:
    a.append(i["date_visit"])

unique = list(set(a))

def get_registers(unique):
    for i in range(len(unique)):
        register =  unique[i]
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + register + ' (name STRING )')
            conn.commit()
        cursor.close()

get_registers(unique)
```

на выходе получаю ошибку

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + register + ' (name STRING )')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "13": syntax error
```

даты берутся в формате **07-08-2020** не понимаю в чем ошибка. Через sqllitestudio таблицы с таким названием создавать можно. в чем тут ошибка?

**UPD**
в `unique` у меня примерно такой список['10-08-2020', '08-04-2020', '14-08-2020'].
соответственно в переменной `register` 10-08-2020

**UPD2**

если удалить знак "-" и перед цифрами поставить букву то добавляется . Но ограничений же на название таблицы вроде нет? Не хочет создавать даже если в названии таблицы первое стоит любое число.

---

может кто-нибудь объяснить почему вот так все работает?

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "' + register + '" (name STRING )')
```

Comment: А что в `register` было перед ошибкой? кст, если используете `with conn`, то можно не вызывать `commit`

Comment: @gil9red, более того, commit здесь не нужен, т.к. после всех DDL операций он выполняется автоматически.

Comment: @gil9red в `register` строка вида 10-08-2020

Comment: `cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + str(register) + ' (name STRING )')`

Comment: вот тут ещё ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257826/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error-python

Comment: @Вадим, таблицы с таким названием не соответствуют правилам именования: `An identifier name must begin with a letter or the underscore character, which is followed by any alphanumeric character or underscore. Other characters are not valid.`. А попробуйте сделать так: `"_" + register.replace("-", "_")` должна получиться таблица с названием `_10_08_2020`. **Кст**, а не проще было сделать таблицу с нормальным названием, но с дополнительным полем -- датой, куда `register` и записывали?

Comment: @gil9red суть в том что хочу создавать таблицы по дате, и в каждую такую записывать зарегистрированный на эту дату. Т.е. сначала из jsona выбираю уникальные даты, по ним создаю таблицы. А потом из этого же jsona раскидываю все данные по таблицам. Возможно перемудрил и это можно сделать как-то проще)

Comment: @Evgeniy `str(register)` не работает . та же ошибка. у меня `register ` и так строка. А ссылка которую вы скинули никакого отношения к названию таблиц не имеет . Пробовал так для названия также как для значений не работало

Comment: @Вадим, вы определенно перемудрили, лучше в одной таблице -- так проще будет обрабатывать даты, да и всегда сможете запросить все данные (по всем датам), и например построить графики. Запрос данных, фильтрация, вывод -- все это проще делать с одной таблицей, а у вас за год таких 365(366) будет. Проблемы с поиском таблиц возникнут -- либо вам их помнить, либо через системные таблицы к ним обращаться. Конечно, это у вас работает, но, мне кажется, что с такой архитектурой будут проблемы. А по поводу вашего ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694291/5909792